# Science-Fiction Film Where Memories Are Extracted With a Vacuum

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have frustratingly vague memories of this because I literally saw two scenes of this and then had to switch channels because it wasn't among the movies my mother would let me watch. It was on the Sci-Fi channel, somewhere in the mid-90s. A man and a woman were fleeing ahead of a guy and his two goons. The guy was extremely pale, and I think older, possibly with white hair. The two goons were bumbling archetypes — I want to say that one of them was fairly chubby — and were dressed in stereotypical dystopian armor, you know, the sort of black stuff that looks like salvaged car parts.

The scene that sticks out in my mind was that the bad guys came upon a body, possibly of a fellow henchman, stuck inside this mucusy stuff, I think pink in color, and the main bad guy told the other two to extract the dead man's memory. What sticks out in my head was that, to remove the memories, they sucked out the brain using a vacuum cleaner hose, a big thick one like used in flowbees. I'm reasonably certain that it had prongs of some sort on the mouth of the hose, probably to lock it into the head. I have a vague memory of this happening inside a long white building, reminiscent of an elementary school, in the middle of a desolate wasteland.

Comment: i presume from your bounty that the answer ***isn't*** Barb Wire? Can you remember anything else that might help such as who the actors were, why they were fleeing the baddies, why the baddies wanted to extract their memories in the first place, etc

Comment: No. I did watch a good chunk of Barb Wire, but it doesn't match up. There was another film that looked like a possible match... but I don't remember its name now. I remember looking at its description, thinking that it actually sounded similar, but couldn't find it in the library or via YouTube at the time.

Comment: Bounty time is typically when you'd try to dredge up something (anything) new that you can remember about the film. For example, how did they suck out the brain? Was it through the ears, the top of the head or the mouth? Did the machine read the brain somehow or did it display their thoughts visually/holographically? Can you describe the woman; was she white, black, tall, short? What was she wearing? Were the actors also dressed in dystopic clothing or was it more futuristic?

Comment: More along the lines of that I was glancing through my stuff and decided to randomly promote a question I'd had in the past. I have nothing new to add, but it had fallen down the list and I figured I'd spend some of my reputation to buoy it. If I can think of anything more, I'll add it.

Comment: Ah. And *[Circuitry Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcw4LtLa4s4)* is the film that looks vaguely right, but none of the scenes in the trailer match up to my memories.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : This is an interesting question, and I tried hard to solve it back in Feb and March.  Thanks for posting the bounty.  I'll try to pick up from where I left off with the research.  You don't have to post new details if you don't have them (contrary to the suggestions of some), and you are free to spend your rep however you please.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : One of the first films I thought of was *Circuitry Man* (and its sequel).  There's memory extraction in both, but neither has the Flowbees-style vacuum or a man trapped in pink goo.  My next thought was *Johnny Mnemomic*, which also gels well with your description (especially the dystopian car-part armor) but it doesn't have the pink mucus or vacuum either.  Since you only saw a few seconds, are you sure it was a film and not a TV series?

Comment: No. I don't know, unfortunately. Thank you for letting me know that Circuitry Man is a miss. I had it on my ILL list just in case. Since it doesn't look like a very good movie overall, I'll cancel it.

And I have seen Johnny Mnemonic and it's not that either.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : Could it have been *Lexx*?  In the US, it aired on Sci-Fi around '97 or '98, starting out as a series of films.  Here's a [scene from the first film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZg43WxUs8).  They refer to the tubes they attach to the chained man's head as "vacs", to cleanse his mind / wipe his memories.  There's a brain exraction immediately after.  The man and woman running could have been Stan Tweedle and Zev.  There's plenty of slime and goo in *Lexx*.

Comment: @Praxis: Yes. But I didn't have time to watch much of the video. What I watched didn't match up, but I'm hoping to watch a bit more tonight.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : It was a longshot --- brain vacuuming of some kind and dystopian armor and slime, but no schools (or "buildings" of any kind for that matter) and no bumbling henchmen.  I'm afraid I'm almost ready to give up on this one!  My only other thought is the *War of the Worlds* TV series --- plenty of slime and mucus, but it doesn't really match any of the other scene elements that you mention.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : It's possible that I'm wrong about *Circuitry Man / Circuitry Man 2* --- it's been a while since I've seen them.  I don't remember a brain vac scene like the one you remember, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Praxis: Possible. Unfortunately, I am having a devil of a time finding the movie so as to watch it. I'm loathe to spend $20 getting a copy on EBay, YouTube doesn't have a copy posted, and Interlibrary Loan has come up dry (apparently, the only library that has it doesn't lend out audiovisual materials).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : You can rent it on iTunes for $3.99 in SD, I believe.

Comment: Huh. Well, that's handy.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete shot in the dark but could it be [Barb Wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barb_Wire_(film)) (1996) starring Pamela Anderson.  The Wikipedia page doesn't mention anything about a memory extraction but I remember them doing one at some point.  The whole movie has lots of leather and would totally fit as one your mother wouldn't want you to see.  They played it on the Sci-Fi channel quite a lot back in the day.

Comment: No. I watched through that and it doesn't match up.