# Name of movie with brain/memory extraction involving chair and needle

Tags: story-identification

I would have seen it on TV in the mid to late 90’s. I remember one scene where there was a set of stairs leading down to a chair contraption. I believe it was a two-sided chair. The victim was on one side, and the villain on the other. The victim had a large syringe type needle come out and screw into the back of the head. Memories/brain power was extracted from the victim and I *believe* inserted into the villain.

Comment: Dark City? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJwoueazGeI

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately no.  No special effects or the like. Might have been produced in 80's.  Once the victim was strapped upright in the chair, the needle/syringe/screw contraption came out of the back of the chair on is own and inserted into the back of the head.  The victim would die when this happens IIRC.

Comment: Related? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80703/science-fiction-film-where-memories-are-extracted-with-a-vacuum

Comment: Take a look at this see if it jogs your memory...http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80703/science-fiction-film-where-memories-are-extracted-with-a-vacuum      Valorum beat me to it by 39 seconds.

Comment: I dont believe there was any sort of pink blob involved as in the ones cited.  Seemed to be more mad scientist with a contraption in a hidden basement as opposed to supernatural type

Comment: The idea of brain material being literally sucked out with a big syringe sounds almost screwy enough to be from [*The Man With Two Brains*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_with_Two_Brains). My own brain material was chemically imbalanced when I last watched that movie so I can't remember if it has the scene you describe. Could you have seen one scene from a comedy film and misinterpreted it as serious horror?

Answer (score 4):

[Friday the 13th, Season 1, Episode 18 "Brain Drain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Friday_the_13th:_The_Series_episodes)

> "Cursed Antique: A trephanator that transfers intelligence from one person, who dies, to another."