# Movie where they could extract people's memories through their eyes

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, steampunk

I think I saw the trailer of this movie when I was a kid, so I could say it's from the early 2000s. I don't remember much about it, but I was both intrigued and terrified. I remember some kind of scientist used syringes on people's eyes and he could control, remove, cut, extract... their memories. Even taking out their eyeballs. It was gruesome. I remember the aesthetic was Steampunk or Art deco, but I'm not sure, because I straight up think about the [*Bioshock* fanmade trailer](https://youtu.be/aSuR1p7bGu8) my brother showed to me at the time. It could be *Dark City* (1998) or *The City of Lost Children* (1995), perhaps?

Comment: Almost certainly Dark City. Doctor Schreber is always injecting people with memories, but it wasn't into their eyeballs; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wJwoueazGeI

Comment: Okay, I googled it and it makes total sense, but I still need to watch the actual movie and confirm it. As I remember it, the way they used syringes on people's eyeballs was very explicit, but maybe it's a fake memory of mine because it terrified me, so... Thank you, anyway (:

Comment: Pretty sure people were injected through the forehead rather than through the eyes in _Dark City_, although I think the camera zoomed in on their eyes to metaphorically show what they were remembering.

Comment: A similar question has been asked before, with no accepted answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141658/name-of-movie-with-brain-memory-extraction-involving-chair-and-needle

Comment: I'm thinking about it and they weren't just syringes, it was about taking people's eyeballs out or something like that? Again, maybe it's just my memory exaggerating it, but... who knows. Gruesome anyways.

Comment: The injections were definitely made through the forehead in _Dark City_. I checked.

Comment: Any chance you might be thinking of _Minority Report_ (2002)...? The main character undergoes surgery to replace his eyeballs in that film, although it had nothing to do with memory extraction. https://youtu.be/sDY6ow3ITCs?t=76

Comment: Oh my god, I think it's that one!! (Minority Report) Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP left a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277095/movie-where-they-could-extract-peoples-memories-through-their-eyes#comment764686_277095) beneath the question indicating that they think the film they were looking for is ***[Minority Report](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/)*** (2002).

> In a future where a special police unit is able to arrest murderers before they commit their crimes, an officer from that unit is himself accused of a future murder.

The story takes place in a mid-21st century version of Washington, D.C. where the police use a trio of clairvoyant mutants known as "precogs" to predict the date and time of imminent murders, enabling them to identify and arrest the would-be perpetrators before the crimes have been carried out.

The film doesn't involve the extraction of people's memories through their eyes, however, there is a scene in which

> a character undergoes illegal eyeball replacement surgery, in order to avoid being correctly identified by the numerous retinal scanners that are peppered throughout the city.

You can view the relevant scene in the video clip below, but it involves spoilers, so bear that in mind if you haven't seen the film.